# Difference between http:// and http://www

Tags: http, web, difference

Can someone please explain the difference between `http://` and `http://www` and the effects of using each of these?

I tried to google but I didn't get much insight. I looked for it on Stackoverflow too, but couldn't find  anything helpful.

Comment: `http://` is a protocol and `www` is the host you client is about to connect to.

Comment: Really? [Google: "why use www in url"](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+use+www+in+url) gives thousands of interesting hits. See for example [What’s the point in having “www” in a URL?](http://serverfault.com/questions/145777/what-s-the-point-in-having-www-in-a-url).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about software development.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't want sarcastic comments. I can give you more ideas on how to 'google' better. If you can answer my question, then do try.

Comment: @Michael-O I need a detailed answer.

Comment: I wasn't being sarcastic. I literally said what I Googled on and gave you a link to it: "why use www in url". What did you search for, what results did that yield and why did they not help?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah, I searched for "why use www in url", and funnily, I also see "why not to use www" (no-www.org) on the same page. I don't want to know "why to use www" in the url, but I want to know the difference between using `http://` and `http://www`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator

Comment: There is **NO** difference. it's all the http protocol. and depending on hose that site's DNS is set up, `www.example.com` and `example.com` **MAY** point at the very same server.

Comment: @MarcB If there was NO difference, then maybe the second `www` shouldn't have existed altogether. I know I talk weird sometimes. I am still searching google trying to understand the difference.

Comment: there used to be a difference. HTTP/1.0 didn't require a `Host` header, and you tended to not mix server roles, so you had `mail.example.com`, `ftp.example.com`, `whatever.example.com`, which meant that the webserver machine naturally became `www.example.com`. `example.com` MAY get mapped to the same ip(s) as www.example.com, but it's not a requirement written anywhere. It's simply a convenience to save people having to type out the `www.`. Nothing says that some company's site can't really be "sedq2345awefrasdrf1234wdrfsdfraw34r23433.example.com", but how many people would type that out?

Comment: `Put on hold as off-topic by...` Then where exactly am I supposed to post this question? Am I on the wrong sub-forum?

Comment: ...and `you guys` don't even care to comment now. Great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
http://
```

is a **protocol**, it tells the client and server what type of connection is being made. Think of it as your browser saying to the server "I am about to send you a HTTP (HyperText Transport Protocol) request". The server then knows how to "see" the request and respond.

Imagine I can speak 8 languages, but can't recognize them without being told. The http:// is the equivalent of saying to me

```
English: Hi Jon, how are you?
```

The English: tells me that you are about to speak English, and that I should respond in the same language.

The http:// simply tells the client and server how to talk to each other

---

```
www
```

This is just a hostname within the domain

eg

```
www.website.com
```

In many (dare I say most?) cases, www.website.com is set up to point directly at website.com, but it could easily be set up to point somewhere else. This very rarely happens, because people have come to expect www. in the URL

This is the equivalent of running a business from your home having several doors in your house, if someone comes in one door, they want your sweet shop. If they come in another, they are coming to your toy shop, and if they use the third, they are visiting your family for a cup of tea

A typical domain will have multiple "hosts", often providing different services. These may be on one server, or each may have it's own server.

eg

ftp.website.com

Points to the server which provides FTP services (file transfer protocol, for sending files)

smtp.website.com

Provides email services, and

www.website.com

Provides "World Wide Web" services (ie a website)

This was the original intention, when typically a company had one domain (company.com) and one example of each service. Nowadays, website use has expanded massively and we will typically provide many more services/websites from one domain, so will use other sub-domains for websites. This is akin to telling you **where** to find a service. "Oh you want the pub? It's down the road and round the corner"

eg

```
customers.website.com
```

May be for a customer login portal, but is still a website. www.website.com has simply endured as the typical use for a "homepage" website, because it has become ingrained in most people's mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You gave a nice overview. I don't even have enough rep for upvoting. And I see that there are a lot of haters around here. Anyways, what do you recommend among the both? What would the advantages or disadvantages be of using www?

Comment: they aren't haters. SO is a forum for solving programming problems so it's justifiable to vote down and appropriate to place on hold as off topic. To get the best out of the site, it's well worth reading the Help Center rules http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: You can't avoid using HTTP. As to www or not, I set my websites up for both to point at the same location. That way if people go to website.com or www.website.com they both point at the same location. In the past they both pointed to the www. address, but now they both point to the non-www address, and I try to use the non-www where possible. For one thing it's slightly shorter and easier to remember, and for two it's superfluous - the "world wide web" isn't really a "thing" to talk about any more. Keep the www. there as a legacy thing.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod But I did ask `Then where exactly am I supposed to post this question? Am I on the wrong sub-forum?` But no one among those who closed it care to reply. Yeah, I went through it just 5mins back. I am new to Stackoverflow, and this 'closing' thing seems a bit oppressive to me. Is this how a new user is treated? And I don't think there's anything wrong with my question, is there?

Comment: Maybe the server admin or web master stack exchange site